# Fine Tuned Universe Numbers

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, physical-constants, fine-tuning, anthropic-principle

I come across many articles for interested lay people telling us that our universe is fine-tuned for life.  For example, if the weak force was a little bit weaker, than almost all of the hydrogen would have been converted to helium in the Big Bang, so not much water or if gravity was a little bit stronger then the life cycle of stars like our sun would be too short for life to have evolved.  I'm very interested in seeing these "little bits" converted into actual percentages or numbers.  Is there a good source for a compilation of tinkering with the 4 forces and the resulting consequences with the actual amount of modification?

Comment: Perhaps this might help:

Dependence of macrophysical phenomena on the values of the fundamental constants W. H. Press and A. P. Lightman 20 December 1983

https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1983.0094

Answer (score 2):

A more recent review is Tegmark, M., Aguirre, A., Rees, M. J., & Wilczek, F. (2006). Dimensionless constants, cosmology, and other dark matters. *Physical Review D*, 73(2), 023505. https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0511774v3